# Can I use the document object in node.js?

Tags: javascript

Can I use the `document` object outside of a browser? Specifically, can I use `document` from node.js, I think I may need to reconstruct the document object. But I want to use methods like `document.getElementById` which is really handful.

Comment: What do you want to call with `document.getElementById`? Maybe we can find a suitable function for you.

Comment: No you can't . Actually all methods are using for DOM  manipulation and node use as server side.

Comment: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think this would be the answer what you want.

have a read the page :)

[docs : createHTMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument)

[docs : createDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createDocument)

and I guess 'Browserify' will be useful.

[docs : browserify](http://browserify.org/)

browserify is a tool for compiling node-flavored commonjs modules for the browser.
so you can use 'require["modules"]' in the browser.